# Where to find (or how to build) rpcapd for my ARM 7 based linux FreshTomato router

Tags: linux, arm, software-rec, router

I had previously found a prebuilt binary for my older MIPS based router running Linux/TomatoUSB, which worked great.  Now of course that binary won't work on my newer ARM based router (Asus AC3200).  I'm having trouble figuring out the best way - does someone out there have a project that builds "extras" like these for open source routers running Tomato, dd-wrt, and others running the MIPS, MIPS2, and ARM processors?  I don't think the router has all of (any of?) the pre-reqs to build from source right on the router, although that could be an option as I have a large USB drive attached to it.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I found an executable rpcapd for ARM processors in a download mentioned in the following forum thread: 
https://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/using-wireshark-with-tomato.34269/page-2

It informs readers that an ARM compiled version of rpcapd can be found at this location:
http://files.lancethepants.com/Binaries/rpcapd/arm/

Just click the filename to download.

I put a copy on my router's mounted thumbdrive, ran it with -d to start as a daemon process, and it works great with Wireshark.

Thank you lancethepants!